# How do I change the position of bins in ggplot2 for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

The following plots a histogram with a bin whose left most point is at 0.

```
myplot = ggplot(df,aes(x = myvar)) +
         geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = .3)
```

I want the histogram to have a bin centered at 0.  (In case you're wondering why I'd want to do such a wacky thing - it's to illustrate some weakness of histograms.)

Comment: Welcome to R on SO.  It's highly recommended to make your code completely reproducible.. Including a sample data set, the library calls, and the expected output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a `breaks` argument to `stat_bin` in the `...`, (`geom_histogram` calls `stat_bin`)

```
myplot <-  ggplot(df,aes(x = myvar))+
 geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), breaks = seq(0,5,by=1))
```

This overrides `bindwidth` and `origin`

see the help for stat_bin for more details.

You may also find `origin` a useful parameter, (setting `origin = 0` perhaps), but not in conjunction with `breaks`!

Comment: The `origin` parameter does what I was hoping. Forces the histogram to start at 0 in stead of being centered on 0. However, `origin` has been deprecated for `boundary` now.